# Pivoting A Table in SQL QUERY with dynamic column heading

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a sql query which uses a subquery as follows:

select mygroup1, mygroup2, tname, @dt, @num,@vec 
  from  TABLE A
WHERE group1 IN
 (
SELECT mygroup1 IN TABLE B 
  WHERE c IS 'blah'
  AND d IS 'blahhh'
)

The table generated is as follows:

```
  mygroup1  mygroup2   tname       @dt      @num   @vek

   a         p          alpha        may      6       a
   b         q          alpha        june     8       b
   c         r          beta         may      9       c
   d         s          beta         june     11      d
```

Now what I actually want from the SQL query is the following table:

```
 mygroup1  mygroup2    alpha@dt    alpha@num    alpha@vec    beta@dt  beta@num  beta@vec
    a         p           may            6            a           nan     nan        nan
    b         q           june           8            b            nan    nan        nan
    c         r           nan            nan        nan            may     9          c
    d         s            nan           nan        nan            june    11         d
```

I know that I can use the PIVOT function of SQL and add a query. I was trying to do it. However, since I am not aggregating and adding names to columns from other column names, my pivot to sql is not working at all. Any help from experts will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is `nan`?  What does this have to do with `pivot`?  And can you explain the logic?

Comment: Nan here means no data for that row or column. The logic is that I have generated the first table from the 1st SQL query. I want to transpose the table (the first two columns, my group and mygroup2 are invariants or grouping) . So the tname column gets transposed with the corresponding column names gets appended to the values in tmame.. I understand it maybe done using dynamic pivoting but not sure how.